# Why do you extend Serializable in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, serialization, deserialization

I'm going through some Sapark projects in Scala, and I see that all of the objects are extending `Serializable` .

It's like :

```
object someName extends Serializable {
//some code
}
```

I understand that serialization is often used for storing or communicating data structures, so that the data can be easily loaded into memory in the original form, from the serialized form. However, in this case the `object` is more like a Java class. So, what's the point or advantage of extending `Serializable` ? When do you do this? Is it necessary to always do this?

Answer (score 6):

**case** objects and **case** classes extend `Product` and `Serializable` automatically. Sometimes traits and abstract classes from [ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) hierarchy are made to extend `Product` and `Serializable` because of type inference reasons.

https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/05/09/product-with-serializable.html

Comment: in scala 3, it does not matter anymore, the type can be inferred successfully to the super type (the abstract class or the trait)

Answer (score 4):

You only actually need it when objects are used *other than calling methods directly on them*. E.g. something like

```
val x = someName

rdd.map { ... x ... }
```

or

```
object SomeName extends Serializable, SomeTrait { ... }

def f(x: SomeTrait) = ...

rdd.map { ... f(SomeName) ... }
```

For "global" `object`s not extending any classes/traits it's basically useless because no one ever does what the first snippet shows, but it doesn't hurt either. Note that `Nil` and `None` are examples of the second and they do extend `Serializable` (even without Spark).

Answer (score 1):

In scala objects are not like java class, they are like java singleton class, if contents of it was required to send over network or they wanted to write to a file. So it has been extended with Serializable trait.